# How is tense handled in a parenthetical clause before a verb?

Tags: grammar, tenses, parentheticals

> She will (or already has) leave for Jamaica soon.
>
> She will leave (or already has left) for Jamaica soon.

I'm uncertain which of these (if either) is more correct. Should I simply not use this language construct, opting for this instead:

> She will leave for Jamaica soon, if she has not already.

I find the previous constructs, despite being awkward, do a better job of conveying the uncertainty of tense. Is there a better way to construct the parenthetical version to avoid tense conflicts?

Comment: As you can see, it is not handled very well. Better to repeat the verb in a different form than try to get them all under one infinitive. So (1) is ungrammatical; and (2) would be better with the adverbs associated with the correct verbs: _She will leave soon (or has already left) for Jamaica._ (3) is fine.

Comment: Regarding the title of your question, did you mean "How _is_ tense handled..."?

Comment: Embarrassing to have blunt typos in the English SE. :-) Thank you for the correction IQAndreas.

Answer (score 1):

> She will leave (or already has left) for Jamaica soon.

I think the word *soon* at the end of your sentence makes the parenthetical awkward. One cannot have left already *soon*.

Also, the correct tense should be at least implied.

Choices (as you note, with adjustment for tense):

> She will *soon* leave (or already has left) for Jamaica.
>   She will *soon* leave (if she has not already left) for Jamaica.
>   She will *soon* leave for Jamaica, if she has not done so already.

I think the uncertainty is clear in the third sentence, and placing the phrase in parentheses doesn't add significantly more emphasis to it than the final construction.